# How to get data from a select option

Tags: php, html, laravel-blade

I am building a calculator using PHP Laravel and I can only use routes. I need to gain access to the value of the option within the select so I can do a calculation once that data is captured.

```
<div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstNumberInput" name="firstNumberInput"
        placeholder="First Number" value="{{Session::get("firstNumber")}}">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6">
    <select class="custom-select mr-3" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
        <option value="add">Addition (+)</option>
        <option value="subtract">Subtraction (-)</option>
        <option value="multiply">Multiplication (*)</option>
        <option value="division">Division (/)</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

So with my `firstNumber` I am capturing the data from what the user inputs, so I need to take that data and whatever they choose from the options I would need to show the outcome for example.. 2 + 2 is 4

Comment: Here is how to get the selected item: https://www.formget.com/php-select-option-and-php-radio-button/

Answer (score 0):

Set name attribute to your Select field.

```
<select class="custom-select mr-3" id="inlineFormCustomSelect" name="operation">
    <option value="add">Addition (+)</option>
    <option value="subtract">Subtraction (-)</option>
    <option value="multiply">Multiplication (*)</option>
    <option value="division">Division (/)</option>
</select>
```

And request by name from your controller.

```
$operation = $request->operation;
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the response, I am sure this would work but I cannot use controllers for this particular assignment. Do you happen to know how I can do this with routes or within the HTML using blade?